# Radio button return same value after submit

Tags: php, html, validation, radio-button

I'm facing a strange error which I cannot figure out. I have a form that submits a set of 2 radio buttons 1 male other female like this:

```
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="femaleRadio" value="f">
    Vrouw
</label>
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="maleRadio" value="m">
    Man
</label>
```

Through jQuery AJAX I send it to php... but when I `echo` the post it always shows that male is selected. Even if I selected the female. Why is this?

```
$gender = strip_tags(trim($_POST['gender']));
echo $gender; exit;
```

I always get M. If I remove the male option in HTML, I get F. This must have a simple solution but I cannot find it.

here is the piece of javascript where i get all the data from the form

```
var el = $(this),

url = el.attr('action'),
type = el.attr('method'),

data = {}

// The loop to get al form data
el.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {

    var el = $(this)
    name = el.attr('name'),
    value = el.val();

    //make data object
    data[name] = value;

});
```

validation of radio buttons on submit

```
//Do some client side validation first
if (!$("#femaleRadio").prop("checked") && !$("#maleRadio").prop("checked")) {

    //Check if radio button is selected
    $('#regError').html("<strong>Fout: </strong> Selecteer een geslacht");
    $('#regError').fadeIn();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As @Songo pointed out you'll have to post you AJAX code. I recreated your project with the given code and it works fine (returns f or m based on what I chose).

Comment: i added the piece that collects the data... after this i just do a ajax call sending the data variable...

Comment: hmm i think i see it now.. i loop trough all the name attributes... but both male and female are named gender.. maybe if i name it male and female it will work ... let me check

Comment: ok now $genderM  = strip_tags(trim($_POST['male'])); $genderF  = strip_tags(trim($_POST['female'])); echo $genderM.$genderF; exit; show m and F but now... i can select male and female (both) because now its not grouped anymore.. thats not good... also... now it will ofcourse always send both variables as if they are both checked....... so what is the best approach to fix this all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this we need to know how radio button works.

All radio buttons in a single group will share same name.

In your case - `gender`.

So, when we select any one option and submit the form, then only the selected radio button's value is stored in the `gender`.

But as per the JavaScript/jQuery code you wrote, you are simply taking the value of each element and take it as the value for it's name.

In this case, you are not checking whether any radio button is selected or not.

You can try following code

```
data['gender'] = $('[name=gender]:checked').val();
```

If nothing is selected - the `gender` property will be undefined.

You can change this logic as needed.

From the code it seems, you are iterating on all available field names. In that case you can update that like this

```
// The loop to get al form data
el.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {

    var el = $(this)
    name = el.attr('name'),
    value = el.val();

    //make data object
    data[name] = value;

    //If this element is a radio button
    if($(this).is(':radio')) {
        data[name] = $('[name=' + name + ']:checked').val();
    }

});
```

Comment: well I have a check that checks if something is checked (added in code). Thats not the problem tough. The problem is that i loop trough the name attributes.. and add each value to data. But now it will always send the M and the F variable to the PHP so i dont know wich value is checked... how can i fix this ?